Combine two cloudwatch log insights queries
I want to combine below two cloudwatch log insights queries
fields @type, @timestamps, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like /Task times out/
| filter toMillis(@timestamp) >= (now() - 86400000)
| stats count_distinct(@logstream) as ErrorCount
| dedup @logstream
fields @type, @timestamps, @message, @logStream
| filter toMillis(@timestamp) >= (now() - 86400000)
| stats count_distinct(@logstream) as TotalCount
| dedup @logstream
I want to get ErrorCount as well as TotalCount in the same output
